# Calculate Variance with Excel ignoring some values

Tags: excel, statistics, variance, deviation

I have two colums :

1. One with data
2. The other with group names. In each cells it's either "Group A" or "Group B".

I would like to calculate Variance with the data from Group A. How could I proceed ?

I've tried

```
Var(If(B1:B10="Group A", A1:A10))
```

But can't nail the proper function.

Comment: That formula works for me, are you confirming with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  This is an array formula and must be entered correctly.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the trick <3